# Tic Tac Toe win conditions in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line

i have an array set up which holds the numbers of a tic tac toe board and console.log()'s which display then in a function.

i need to make it so once a winning line is achieved a message will show up saying winner or whatever.

here is what i have

```
var boardsq = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"];

function boardDisplay() {
    console.log("| "+boardsq[0]+" | "+boardsq[1]+" | "+boardsq[2]+" |");
    console.log("| "+boardsq[3]+" | "+boardsq[4]+" | "+boardsq[5]+" |");
    console.log("| "+boardsq[6]+" | "+boardsq[7]+" | "+boardsq[8]+" |");
}
```

Am I right in saying I need the && and || operators

Comment: *"Am I right in saying I need the && and || operators"* Probably. A solution that doesn't use `&&` or `||` would be extremely contrived. Providing you with a solution is too broad a question, off-topic for this site

Comment: Not sure what you mean.